Improve FindInstance, or better yet just Solve!
This one is seemingly not that complex, yet I am not getting Mathematica to return a solution in a timely manner:  (I have 2 variables, t - an angle and k a length)
Solve[10*k*Sin[54 Degree - (t/2) Degree] + ((t/360)*Pi*k^2) == 
   15*Sqrt[10*(5 + Sqrt[5])] && 
  10*Sin[108 Degree] == k*Sin[18 Degree + (t/2) Degree] , {k, t}]

Not sure if I have to keep saying "Degree" also, as once it confused it to Radians.
If I out the same one to FindInstance....Same thing! Keeps spinning.
Please note if I graphically draw the 2nd equation:  kSin[18 +(t/2)]-10Sin[108]=0 and put a variable t in place, I can see that t should be between 5.6 and 6.7 so that k is between 10 and ~15  as this is actually part of a geometry problem which I can see viaually my k has those limits.   However none of that should matter, as the equations should be self-sufficient.
Exact-value solution would be preferred of course!
Thanks!

Like I said, it does not return a value and takes forever, regardless of whether it's FindInstance or Solve.

Ah yes! Thanks....Bob pointed out the version..I am on 12. So this is the issue!

Yeah if you know who those people are, do point them to me...  Note none of the conversation here insinuated anything as such.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Set constraints on the parameters, for example,
sol = Solve[{10*k*Sin[54  Degree - (t/2)  Degree] + ((t/360)*Pi*k^2) == 
     15*Sqrt[10*(5 + Sqrt[5])] && 
    10*Sin[108  Degree] == k*Sin[18  Degree + (t/2)  Degree], -20 <= k <= 20, 
   0 <= t <= 360}, {k, t}]


sol // N

(* {{k -> 12.0608, t -> 68.1011}, {k -> 10.8396, t -> 201.342}} *)

EDIT: Per change in comment
sol2 = Solve[{10*k*Sin[54   Degree - (t/2)   Degree] + ((t/360)*Pi*k^2) == 
     75*Sqrt[1 + (2/Sqrt[5])] && 
    10*Sin[108   Degree] == k*Sin[18   Degree + (t/2)   Degree], -20 <= k <= 
    20, 0 <= t <= 360}, {k, t}]


sol2 // N

(* {{k -> 10.1535, t -> 184.997}, {k -> 10.5001, t -> 93.8519}} *)


Ok thanks Bob!  My verions is 12.1.1, so are you saying they improved it THAT much as to speed this up?  As you left my own (almost) intact, just added ranges. Also:  How can I get exact values for the expressions inside boxes with blue square roots? Why do they represent it that way?

The Root expressions are exact. These specific values cannot be represented by algebraic expressions. ToRadicals can convert some Root expressions, but not in this case.

Hi @Bob Hanlon:  Can you rerun the results with replacing this part:  15Sqrt[10(5 + Sqrt[5])]   with 75*Sqrt[1+(2/Sqrt[5])]  please! I made an error on that section and do not have v14!   I expect k=10.5001 with t=93.8514   Thanks!

Note that you can use the Wolfram Cloud to remotely execute using the latest version

Ok sure will do...


It seems that there are three roots.

ContourPlot[{10*k*Sin[54 Degree - (t/2) Degree] + ((t/360)*Pi*k^2) == 
   15*Sqrt[10*(5 + Sqrt[5])], 
  10*Sin[108 Degree] - (k*Sin[18 Degree + (t/2) Degree])}, {k, -80, 
  80}, {t, -100, 500}]



Since Version 12.0 cann't sove or findinstance such roots, we have to use FindRoot.

plot = ContourPlot[
   10*k*Sin[54 Degree - (t/2) Degree] + ((t/360)*Pi*k^2) == 
    15*Sqrt[10*(5 + Sqrt[5])], {k, -80, 80}, {t, -100, 500}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {0 &, 
     Function[{k, t}, 
      10*Sin[108 Degree] - (k*Sin[18 Degree + (t/2) Degree])]}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive@{AbsolutePointSize[10], Red}]


pts = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[{pts__}, __] :> pts, -1];
meshindexs = First@Cases[plot[[1]], Point[i_] :> i, -1];
values = Rationalize[pts[[meshindexs]], 0];
FindRoot[10*k*Sin[54 Degree - (t/2) Degree] + ((t/360)*Pi*k^2) == 
     15*Sqrt[10*(5 + Sqrt[5])] && 
    10*Sin[108 Degree] == 
     k*Sin[18 Degree + (t/2) Degree], {{k, #1}, {t, #2}}] & @@@ values


{{k -> 50.2352, t -> -14.1737}, {k -> 12.0608,  t -> 68.1011}, {k -> 10.8396, t -> 201.342}}


Good to see this visually! my v12 still does not return your "Cases" results.   Also note i know 0<t<108 degrees Hence your middle solution is the one, matching Bob's

Can you help me understand how to get exact values behind the solution provided by Bob? See below comment...

Never mind, found the answers to Root Objects.
